# selendroid: unable to inspect the element

Tags: selendroid

Hi i'm a new bee in Selendroid can someone please tell me why im getting this error when i launch the URL `http://localhost:4444/inspector` .. my automation works fine but im unable to view the app in `http://localhost:4444/inspector` link (during added a break point into the test code and run the test in debug mode) can someone please help on this.

```
INFO: inspector screenshot handler, sessionId: b93ee863-3b05-0fed-73a3-eaeadb6fa1c5
io.selendroid.exceptions.AndroidDeviceException: Device not accessible via ddmlib.
    at io.selendroid.android.impl.AbstractDevice.takeScreenshot(AbstractDevice.java:363)
    at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.takeScreenshot(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:531)
    at io.selendroid.server.handler.InspectorScreenshotHandler.handle(InspectorScreenshotHandler.java:56)
    at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidServlet.handleRequest(SelendroidServlet.java:140)
    at io.selendroid.server.BaseServlet.handleHttpRequest(BaseServlet.java:70)
    at org.webbitserver.netty.NettyHttpControl.nextHandler(NettyHttpControl.java:78)
    at org.webbitserver.netty.NettyHttpControl.nextHandler(NettyHttpControl.java:62)
    at org.webbitserver.handler.PathMatchHandler.handleHttpRequest(PathMatchHandler.java:33)
    at org.webbitserver.netty.NettyHttpControl.nextHandler(NettyHttpControl.java:78)
    at org.webbitserver.netty.NettyHttpControl.nextHandler(NettyHttpControl.java:62)
    at org.webbitserver.handler.DateHeaderHandler.handleHttpRequest(DateHeaderHandler.java:21)
    at org.webbitserver.netty.NettyHttpControl.nextHandler(NettyHttpControl.java:78)
    at org.webbitserver.netty.NettyHttpControl.nextHandler(NettyHttpControl.java:62)
    at org.webbitserver.handler.ServerHeaderHandler.handleHttpRequest(ServerHeaderHandler.java:25)
    at org.webbitserver.netty.NettyHttpControl.nextHandler(NettyHttpControl.java:78)
    at org.webbitserver.netty.NettyHttpControl.nextHandler(NettyHttpControl.java:67)
    at org.webbitserver.netty.NettyHttpChannelHandler$2.run(NettyHttpChannelHandler.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same issue , but I am using physical  device. I slowed this issue, solunion is clenched the temp folder and really start the selendroid  server, then it works fine. This thing working fine with me, try this way may be it helps hope so..

Comment: Venkataramana, try with the latest version of Selendroid may fix your problem